Angular 16: My form's input values are not cached by the browser when the form is inside an ng-container
In my Angular project I have the following form.
test.component.html:
<ng-container
  *ngIf="{
    loading: loading$ | async,
    options: options$ | async,
  } as vm"
>
  <form [formGroup]="testForm" class="col-12">
    <label for="ticket">First name:</label>

    <input
      type="text"
      pInputText
      class="form-control"
      autocomplete="on"
      id="ticket"
      name="ticket"
      formControlName="ticket"
    />

    <button class="btn btn-primary" icon="pi pi-check" [disabled]="testForm.invalid" (mousedown)="onSubmit()">
      {{ 'NN-COMMON.SAVE' | translate }}
    </button>
  </form>

......


</ng-container>


test.component.ts:
  private test(): FormGroup<{ ticket: FormControl<string> }> {
    const conf: FormGroupConfigType<{ticket: FormControl<string>}> = {
      ticket: ['', null]
    }

    const form = this.fb.group(conf) as FormGroup<{ticket: FormControl<string>}>;

    return form;
  }

The problem is that the browser does not cache the values of the input and I want it to cached.
Notes:
- My form is inside an <ng-container> because I have some observables that I need to subscribe to at the template. (Sorry I can not share all the code because it is a private project)
- the onSubmit() function is a POST request to the BackEnd
- In general, the form is affected by a lot of asynchronous operations. Both on Set or Update values.
What did I try:

Make sure that id and name are set correctly and use the autocomplete = "on"

Set the form outside of the <ng-container> and check if it works. 98% of the times it works fine.
So, my problem seems that is the <ng-container> but I can not get rid of it.


Why is this might happening?
Any ideas of how can I solve it?
Thank you in advance!! :)

what do you mean by browser cache? is the form not updated? could you give the minimal code where the issue happens?

Hello!!
I mean that the browser does not cache the value of the input and the next time I enter it, it does not hint the previous values.
e.g Imagine a login form where you can see the username that you have already use.

could you give the minimal code where the issue happens?
I would try to create one , but the current code is extremely big and complex which I am not sure that I can replicate on a dummy one.


have you tried (ngSubmit) in the form tag and type="submit"on the button tag?

I think it's related to autocomplete attribute of one input, not related to the ng-container

This is interesting problem and I think @JSmith is on a right track: browsers persist  ("remember", or "cache" as you put it) only values that were actually submitted from named inputs, or more precisely that were entered the moment the submit event of the form was fired (it does not need to actually send the data to a server).  It creates a global name-keyed register, i.e. whatever you fill and "submit" through <input name="gazonk"> you'll get suggested (autocompleted) in any "gazonk"-named input on any page in the same browser, if not forbidden by attribute or other policy.

@myf I have also (keydown.control.enter)="onSubmit()" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" in the original code. But still it does not work :/ (Sorry that I forgot to mention it)

@EiriniTepelidou well I am not much fluent in NG so I am not sure what exactly these bindings really do, but I suspect that the "manual" (ng)OnSubmit invokers only mean "do the work that I've issued to be done when the form is submitted", but my theory is that it is not in fact doing the submit itself, and because the fact the submit never actually happens, no autofill record is being created. Can you try appending simple extra <input type="submit" /> without any event handler into your form and click it, to see if it would behave differently?
